# How to check if an element of an array is a special character?

Tags: c

I've heard of isdigit() and isalpha(), however I just wanted to know if there is some sort of function in C which I can use to determine whether something is a special character (#, %, *, $, etc.).

Also if anyone knows a function which can determine whether something is not only a letter, but whether it is an uppercase or lowercase letter, and share that as well - that would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Uppercase -> `isupper()` Lowercase -> `islower()`

Comment: Looks through these listed here https://linux.die.net/man/3/isprint and see what you need.

Comment: There is a *family* of [character classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/character-classification?view=msvc-160) functions.

Comment: You can make your own test using `strchr("#%*$", character)` for example.

Comment: You can use `ispunct()` from [`<ctype.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4) to find printing characters that are graphic characters but not letters or digits.  A space is not a graphic character, even though it is a printing character.  Note that `isgraph()`, `isprint()`, `iscntrl()` are other character classifying functions, as well as `isalpha()`, `islower()`, `isupper()`, `isdigit()`, `isalnum()`, `isblank()`, `isspace()`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h> 
  
void charCheck(char input_char) 
{ 
    if(!(input_char >='a' && input_char<='z')  && !(input_char >='A' && input_char<='Z') && !(input_char >='0' && input_char<='9'))
    {
        printf("Special character\n");   
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Not a special character\n");
    }
    
} 
  
// Driver Code 
int main() 
{ 

    char input_char[] = "abng@#$^^&"; 
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       charCheck(input_char[i]);
    }
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Special character is neither an alphabet nor a number. The output is :

```
Not a special character
Not a special character
Not a special character
Not a special character
Special character
Special character
Special character
Special character
Special character
Special character
```

> whether it is an uppercase or lowercase letter

Answer : `islower()`, `isupper()`

Comment: Why not just use `isalnum()`?

Comment: Never heard of it. Thanks. So we can just use `!isalnum()`

Comment: It's not quite as simple as `!isalnum()` — there are control characters (`iscntrl()`) which are not punctuation characters, and then `isspace()` and `isblank()` too.  The best function for identifying punctuation is `ispunct()` (surprise, surprise), unless you don't want to count certain characters as punctuation (e.g. you want to treat apostrophes as a valid part of words such as "don't").

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, but `!isalnum()` is equivalent to the condition in this answer :)